# How can I add a list element on a Python Django website via button?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a little music website and I already have two albums and their songs. But how can I add a new Album or a new Song to my Database but on the Interface of the website? I have two Textfields for the Album (Artist, Title) and one for the Songs (just title). When you click the button it links you to another page where you can type in the title etc. Then the data should be saved in the Database and also displayed on the website.
That's my template for the Album site. The Song site is similar:

my views.py for CreateView

```
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/album_form.html'
    fields = ['artist', 'title']
```

and my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
  url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
  url(r'^album-add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),
  url(r'^song-add/$', views.SongCreate.as_view(), name='song-add')
```

and my album_form.html template

```html
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <h2>Add Album</h2>
        <input placeholder="Enter Artist size="30"><br><br>
        <input placeholder="Enter Albumtitle" size="30"><br>
    </div>
</form>

        <a href="{% url 'music:index' %}">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </a>
```

and here is my index.html template where all the Albums are displayed

```html
<ul>
    {% for album in object_list %}
    <li><a href = "{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{album.artist}} - {{album.title}} </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: `<input placeholder="Enter Artist size="30">` and `<input placeholder="Enter Albumtitle" size="30">` would have to be django form inputs. In your views.py you would validate the form and save it to the database

Comment: This is a classic use case covered by the django docs. I hate to give an RTM answer but https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/